# Find column Vbscript PowerDesigner

Tags: vbscript, powerdesigner

I would like to find column in tables.
Why I have mistake when I run VBscript in Power Designer?

```
Dim table, column
for each table in activeModel.tables
for each column in table.columns
output column.name
next
next
```

Mistake is Object doesn't support this property or method: 'columns'.

Comment: Maybe you're picking Shortcuts. You should display the `table` type, `output table.name&":"&table.classname`.

Comment: If it's the case, you can add a test like `if table.classkind = cls_table then` before looping on `table` columns.

Comment: thank you, I tried both, but it didnt work..`output table.name&":"&table.classname`  just shows me name of tables but not name of columns.

Comment: Displaying `table.classname` was to try to identify the kind of objects that the script finds in the `ActiveModel.Tables` collection, and which are not `Table`, to fix the `Object doesn't support this property or method: 'columns'` error.